# Wordpress on IIS with shared wp-content

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, permissions

I've been trying to install Wordpress on IIS and everything went smoothly with a standard installation and an handler mapping for php-cgi.

Since I have a public server (A) and a private shared server (B), I need to have a WP installation on server A with a shared database and shared wp-content on server B.

The main issue is configuring a Virtual Directory on IIS for wp-content on server B with the required permissions.
The Wordpress on server A is able to access the media resources (images and other files). Through wp-admin, I can also access and upload new resources to the shared wp-content.

The problem starts as soon as I try to see the installed plugins or install new ones, since WP can't access the plugins folder, and, as a consequence, the website can't be viewed as well.

I've already tried several things in order to solve the referred problem.

The steps I tried, not necessarily in this order, were:

- Created an user on both machines with the required permissions on wp-content;
- Gave full access permissions to that user (also Everyone) on wp-content;
- Created a Virtual Directory on IIS and Connecting As the created user;
- Running the Default Web Site APP Pool with that user;

At the step I'm at, the wordpress does not load the installed plugins and asks for FTP credentials while trying to install new ones.

It seems to me that the problem may be with additional permissions that I don't know about.

If anyone has successfully accessed a shared wp-content with IIS, please help me before I go mad.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Assuming Server B will read from Server A's wp-content. I have honestly never heard of anyone trying this. Not impossible though. My comment was getting long so moving it to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

```
+-----------+      +----------+
|  Server A | <--  | Server B |
+-----------+      +----------+
```

First, lets look at the App Pool for Server A -> Site A and Server B -> Site B. I would advise using Impersonation versus a service account. This will allow you to leverage AD or Local Users.

Second test with the UNC path in Explorer from Server B to Server A (\server-a\wp-content). If you have not setup a share, you may want to do this. You're going to encounter speed issues etc, but I don't think it will be bad. Map a drive, for example `Z:\`, to this path.

If you stick with a service account, make sure that `IIS_IUSR` and `Users` groups have Read & Execute permissions and make sure the Computer account of Server B is a member of those groups (create a computer account for Server B if needed).

If we get this far, I think we need a symbolic link. A virtual directory would be great but does not work for file system calls from PHP. For example if a page attempts to make a include not using a URL path.

This should help: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

On Server B run something like:

```
mklink /J C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wp-content Z:\
```

Adjust for the proper paths on your server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I used some of your suggestions and came up with a solution I'll describe on an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the situation described on the initial question

```
+---------------------+      +-----------------------------+
|  Server A (IIS / WP)| -->  | Server B (wp-content/mySQL) |
+---------------------+      +-----------------------------+
```

Solution:

- Create user X on servers A and B with same credentials;
- on server B, share wp-content with user X (full permissions);
- on server B, set FULL CONTROL security permissions to user X;
- on server A, add user X to group IIS_IUSRS;
- on server A, create a symbolic link as referred by @Twisty (Ex.: mklink /d c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wp-content \\);
- on server A, set FULL CONTROL security permissions to user X on the symbolic link (c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wp-content);
- on server A, on IIS, run the Default Web Site as user X (Default Web Site -> Basic Settings -> Connect as... -> Specific user);
- on server A, iisreset just to be safe.